# Is $g \circ f: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $ \mu$-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to show the following:

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ for which a non-measurable subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ exist. Further, let $f: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ functions:

> If $ g \circ f: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mu $-measurable, then $g$ is $\mu$-measurable;
>
> If $g \circ f: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mu$-measurable,
> then $f$ is $\mu$-measurable;

I realise that both statements are not correct. But how could I show this clearly by means of a contradiction?

I have considered the following:
To disprove the first statement, assume that $f$ is not $\mu$-measurable, but $g \circ f$ is $\mu$ measurable. This doesn't necessarily imply that $g$ is $\mu$-measurable. Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is not $\mu$-measurable. Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the identity function, i.e., $g(x)=x$. Then, 4g \circ f=f$ for all $x$. Since $f$ is not $\mu$-measurable, $f$ is also not $\mu$-measurable.

To disprove the second statement, I assume that $g \circ f$ is not $\mu$-measurable, but $f$ is $\mu$ measurable. This doesn't necessarily imply that $f \circ g$ is $\mu$-measurable. Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is $\mu$-measurable, and let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is not $\mu$-measurable. Then, $f \circ g=f$ for all $x $. Since $ g $ is not $\mu$-measurable, $f \circ g$ is also not $\mu $ measurable.

Would that be a correct refutation?

Comment: Use indicator functions for $E$ and constant functions

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't get me any further: I realized that $g \circ f$ is measurable iff $ (g \circ f)^{-1}((\alpha, \infty))$ is measurable for al $\alpha$- But how can I now construct the proof to the contrary?